# Changes disappearing in Xcode 4 project

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I am having this weird problem, it's making me question my sanity, but I have proof. Ok, so I do freelance, and I am writing this app for someone. Basically, I make some changes and upload the improved xcode project directory on the freelance website and he provides feedback. It worked fine for the first 3 weeks but then....

I sent him the xcode project folder with new changes. He said wtf? You haven't made any changes. So I recorded my screen, downloaded the project file that I sent him from the website (to which I upload..) and showed him that changes indeed have been made. I have the recording still. He still persisted that there are no changes. I thought he was bsing....

After about a week, I heard back from him asking "Can you exactly describe in which file you made changes and on what file?". I was excited as I thought I would prove him wrong but telling him the changes I made.

So I opened the xcode project, and INDEED all the changes I made were gone!! Then I thouhgt ok, maybe for some odd reason my changes were reverted, I am going to download the file from the website and use that...
I downloaded the file from the website and the changes weren't there as well. The weird part is, I HAVE the screen recording of me downloading that file a week ago and showing that the changes were made.

What is going on? Is it some new XCode4 feature that I am missing? Please help.

Comment: You probably just copied the project folder in the wrong direction at some point, overwriting the newer version - just pull the newer version from your version control or backup system, whichever is more convenient.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using a file syncing service like Dropbox would you? I've witnessed firsthand issues with working on the project while it's still in the Dropbox folder and being actively synced. Changes disappearing, text corruptions, etc.

Comment: Nop. No version control, no git, no dropbox. Simply edit and command-save.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why this eludes you, but I have been unable to replicate this myself. I do have some suspicions however, that i belive may be the source of it.

1) with 4.0 came some solid integration with GIT repositories. Make sure that all your changes are committed my rightclicking your project in the left side pane and select "submit changes" (or something similar, can't recall the name) this should ensure that the files in the project folder are subject to your changes.

2) Make sure that the files you are working on are not remotely linked to files elsewhere. Make a systemwide search for a file from your project with a unique filename. See if that file exists anywhere else, and if that file's last changed date goes up when you edit something. If this is the case, reimort it with the copy setting ON.

Hope this solves your XCode mysteries.